# Pointing at Access controls, Visual Basic

Tags: ms-access, vba

My function:

```
Public Function openRpt(strReportName As String, form as ??, subform as ??)
    On Error Resume Next
    If (Forms![form]![subform].Form.lock = False) Then
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    End If
    DoCmd.OpenReport strReportName, acViewPreview, "", _
        "[num]=Forms![form]![subform].Form.[num]"
End Function
```

What it does is to save a record from `subform` if it isn't locked, and then launch a report. I want to switch `from` and `subform` with matching variables that will point at the right forms, and will be given as arguments.

1. What type of variable should I use?
2. What is the difference between using '!' and '.' to access properties? I understand that '!' is used to access a controller and '.' is used to access a table record, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for (1):
First, it may be tempting to call variables form and subform, but watch out for possible errors if names you use match or are close to reserved names.
Also, lock is not a valid property of a form or subform. If you are trying to test if a form has been changed, you would test `.Dirty`
This is how I would code your function:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function openRpt(strReportName As String, frm as String, sFrm as string)
    If (Forms(frm).Form(sFrm).Form.Dirty = True) Then
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    End If
    DoCmd.OpenReport strReportName, acViewPreview, "", _
        "[num]=Forms(""" & frm & """).Forms(""" & sFrm & """).Form.[num]"
End Function
```

for (2):
from the [Microsoft Blog](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2008/05/30/dot-or-bang.aspx)

- The dot gives you early binding and is resolved at compile time, the bang is resolved at runtime.
- In the case of Forms, both controls and fields in the underlying query can be referenced via a dot since they are all in the type library for the form.
- Also in the case of Forms, if you change the underlying query at runtime - dot references to the old query's fields will fail at runtime since update of the Form's type library cannot happen at runtime.
- Because the dot is early bound, IntelliSense happens by default with the dot, not with the bang.
- The dot (since it is early bound) is faster than the bang, but no one runs enough code that uses these items enough for the performance difference to actually matter.